# R - within and ave using multiple inputs

Tags: r

I have been using functions `with` and `ave` in the following manner:

```
DT = within(DT,{sim1 = ave(sample, no, FUN = sample_ret)})
```

This function takes data.table `DT` and segments it by variable `no`. After that, it applies function `sample_ret` with input `sample` and creates another column `sim1` in the data.table.

Is there a way that I can make the function take multiple inputs? For example, instead of just taking `sample`, how can I let function `sample_ret` take another column along with `sample`?

If this is not possible, is there another function that can accomplish what I want? Basically, I want to segment the data.table and apply a function using more than one column as the inputs?

For example, data.table `DT`:

```
COL1 COL2 TYPE COL4
1    2    A    4
5    6    A    8
9    10   B   12
13   14   B   16
3    34   A   16
1    2    C   16
```

And I want to segment `DT` by `TYPE` and then how many values are greater than 6 in `COL1` and how many values are greater than 12 in `COL2` per each `TYPE`. Let's say that I have a function `greater_than` that takes in two columns and does exactly that. How can I accomplish what I want with `ave` or some other alternative?

Comment: Show some sample input and sample output. Also, there is likely no need to be using `ave` if you are working with `data.table`s.

Comment: What's the alternative to <code>ave</code>?

Comment: See `?data.table`. In your example, something like `DT[,sim1:=sample_ret(sample),by=no]` should be equivalent to your line (and in virtually every case much faster).

Comment: Share some sample input and output and someone would be able to demonstrate it. Most likely the `by` argument when using `data.table`s would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base R` option would be

```
indx <- df1[1:2] >val[col(df1[1:2])]
rownames(indx) <- df1$TYPE
rowsum(indx+0L, row.names(indx))
#    COL1 COL2
#A    0    1
#B    2    1
#C    0    0
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(TYPE) %>%
     mutate_each(funs(.>df2$.), COL1:COL2) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(sum), COL1:COL2)
#  TYPE COL1 COL2
#1    A    0    1
#2    B    2    1
#3    C    0    0
```

Or a possible `data.table` option suggested by @David Arenburg

```
library(data.table)
cols <- paste0("COL", 1:2)
sums <- function(x, y) sum(x > y) 
setDT(df1)[, Map(sums, .SD, val), by=TYPE, .SDcols = cols]
#    TYPE COL1 COL2
#1:    A    0    1
#2:    B    2    1
#3:    C    0    0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(COL1 = c(1L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 1L), COL2 = c(2L, 
6L, 10L, 14L, 34L, 2L), TYPE = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"
), COL4 = c(4L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 16L)), .Names = c("COL1", 
"COL2", "TYPE", "COL4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- data.frame(COL1=6, COL2= 12)
val <- c(6,12)
```

Comment: Dunno, `val <- c(6, 12) ; cols <- paste0("COL", 1:2) ; setDT(df1)[, as.list(mapply(function(x, y) sum(x > y), mget(cols), val)), by = TYPE]` maybe?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I came up with a `for` loop, but thought that it was less elegant.  `val <- c(6,12);
 for(j in 1:2){
 df1[, paste0('val', j) :=sum(.SD>val[j]), TYPE ,.SDcols=j]
 }
;
unique(df1[,c('TYPE', 'val1', 'val2'), with=FALSE], by='TYPE')`

Comment: @DavidArenburg You could post that as an answer.  I haven't seen anybody using `mapply` within `data.table`, but it looks better than my approach.

Comment: Na, you can add it to yours of you wish as I didn't even understood the question until you posted your solutions